# how to get the redirect response in c# when I sent the get request to the web

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I try to send a get request [A] to the web. I can receive the response [A] from the web. The response [A] is a HTML and it has a javascript to submit a form [B] by post method when the page was loaded. Now, I would like to send the get request [A] and receive the response [B] of the last one which is the form response. Since the javascript has some complicated calculation, I do not want to rewrite the logic in c#.

How do I can receive the response [B] of the form when I send the get request [A]?

```
HttpWebResponse response;
string strhtml;
CookieCollection cook;
cook =  new CookieCollection();
response = HttpWebResponseUtility.CreateGetHttpResponse(url, null, "", 
cookie);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
strhtml  = sr.ReadToEnd();
//I can receive the response [A] which is a HTML.
sr.Close();
response.Close();



public static HttpWebResponse CreateGetHttpResponse(string url, int? 
timeout, string userAgent, CookieCollection cookies)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        }
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UserAgent = DefaultUserAgent;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
        {
            request.UserAgent = userAgent;
        }
        if (timeout.HasValue)
        {
            request.Timeout = timeout.Value;
        }
        if (cookies != null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        }
        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

`

Comment: What is this for? MVC? ASP? Winforms?

Comment: Winforms........

Comment: Show us your code? and please tag the question [tag:Winforms]

Comment: ok.............